# (Possibly) Complex Join across four tables using aggregates

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to join a 'master' table, Account, to three related tables and apply some WHERE criteria on each.

Here's the query I've got so far:

```
SELECT Account.Name
     , AnnAccs.PeriodEnd AS AnnAccsPeriodEnd
     , AnnAccs.LastPeriod AS AnnAccsLastPeriod
     , CorpTax.PeriodEnd AS CorpTaxPeriodEnd
     , CorpTax.LastPeriod AS CorpTaxLastPeriod
     , SelfAss.PeriodEnd AS SAPeriodEnd
     , SelfAss.LastPeriod AS SALastPeriod
  FROM dbo.Account
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(new_corporationtaxactivity.new_PeriodEnd) AS PeriodEnd
                  , new_corporationtaxactivity.new_LastPeriod AS LastPeriod
                  , new_CorporationTaxActivityId AS AccId
               from new_corporationtaxactivity 
              GROUP BY 
                    new_CorporationTaxActivityId
                  , new_corporationtaxactivity.new_LastPeriod
            ) AS CorpTax 

    ON CorpTax.AccId = Account.AccountId 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(new_annualaccountsactivity.new_PeriodEnd) AS PeriodEnd
                  , new_annualaccountsactivity.new_LastPeriod AS LastPeriod
                  , new_AnnualAccountsActivityId AS AccId 
               from new_annualaccountsactivity 
              GROUP BY 
                    new_AnnualAccountsActivityId
                  , new_annualaccountsactivity.new_LastPeriod
            ) AS AnnAccs 
    ON AnnAccs.AccId = Account.AccountId
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(new_selfassessmentactivity.new_PeriodEnd) AS PeriodEnd
                  , new_selfassessmentactivity.new_LastPeriod AS LastPeriod
                  , new_SelfAssessmentActivityId AS AccId 
               from new_selfassessmentactivity 
              GROUP BY 
                    new_SelfAssessmentActivityId
                  , new_selfassessmentactivity.new_LastPeriod
            ) As SelfAss 
    ON SelfAss.AccId = Account.AccountId
 WHERE (    Account.new_ClientStatus = '100000000' 
         OR Account.new_ClientStatus = '100000001')
   AND (    AnnAccs.LastPeriod = '1' 
         OR CorpTax.LastPeriod = '1' 
         OR SelfAss.LastPeriod = '1')
```

The Account table is 1:* with the three related tables, and I want to do the following: for each account, check to see if the latest/most current activity within each related table (be it Annual Accounts, Corporation Tax, or Self Assessment), of which there may be none, is marked as 'Last Period'.

So for example, one account may have a Self Assessment activity (i.e. one row in the Self Assessment view/table) and no other related activities, so I would want to see something like:

```
AccName  |  AnnAccsPeriodEnd  |  AnnAccsLastPeriod  |  CorpTaxPeriodEnd  |  CorpTaxLastPeriod  |  SAPeriodEnd  |  SALastPeriod
AccA     |              null  |               null  |              null  |               null  |   01/01/2014  |          true
```

Similarly, it might have an annual accounts activity that isn't null, but still isn't marked as 'LastPeriod':

```
AccName  |  AnnAccsPeriodEnd  |  AnnAccsLastPeriod  |  CorpTaxPeriodEnd  |  CorpTaxLastPeriod  |  SAPeriodEnd  |  SALastPeriod
AccA     |        01/01/2014  |              false  |              null  |               null  |   01/01/2014  |          true
```

So for each account where one of the activities is marked as 'LastPeriod', I want just one row (one account, possibly 1-2 of the related tables' columns as null, at least one always having data where LastPeriod = true).

The query above is giving strange results that look almost look like a cross or full join, so each account will result in 3-4 rows for example.

I've been bending my mind on this for the past couple of days - any help would be much appreciated!

If I can improve the question with more detail just let me know!

(Thanks for the edits!)

Comment: Sometimes using something like SQLfiddle.com helps in cases like this.

Comment: Each of your subqueries groups by two columns but only joins on one, so unless you can guarantee that there will only be one row per account in each table where `LastPeriod = 1`, then it is not surprising you are getting cross joins.

Comment: @GarethD Ah yea that's probably it, good thinking! Can you recommend a way to avoid it? The only row I'm interested in in each of the sub-tables is the latest one (by new_PeriodEnd), so in my results I only want to see the latest from each and discard the rest if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the latest row you can turn each of your subqueries into an [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT  Account.Name, 
        AnnAccs.PeriodEnd AS AnnAccsPeriodEnd, 
        AnnAccs.LastPeriod AS AnnAccsLastPeriod,
        CorpTax.PeriodEnd AS CorpTaxPeriodEnd, 
        CorpTax.LastPeriod AS CorpTaxLastPeriod,
        SelfAss.PeriodEnd AS SAPeriodEnd, 
        SelfAss.LastPeriod AS SALastPeriod
FROM    dbo.Account 
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1
                    ca.new_PeriodEnd AS PeriodEnd, 
                    ca.new_LastPeriod AS LastPeriod, 
                    new_CorporationTaxActivityId AS AccId 
            FROM    new_corporationtaxactivity ca
            WHERE   ca.AccId = Account.AccountId 
            ORDER BY ca.new_PeriodEnd DESC
        ) AS CorpTax 
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 aa.new_PeriodEnd AS PeriodEnd, 
                    aa.new_LastPeriod AS LastPeriod, 
                    aa.new_AnnualAccountsActivityId AS AccId 
            FROM    new_annualaccountsactivity aa
            WHERE   aa.new_AnnualAccountsActivityId = Account.AccountId 
            ORDER BY aa.new_PeriodEnd DESC
        ) AS AnnAccs 
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 sa.new_PeriodEnd AS PeriodEnd, 
                    sa.new_LastPeriod AS LastPeriod, 
                    sa.new_SelfAssessmentActivityId AS AccId 
            FROM    new_selfassessmentactivity sa
            WHERE   sa.new_SelfAssessmentActivityId = Account.AccountId
            ORDER BY sa.new_PeriodEnd DESC
        ) As SelfAss 
WHERE   (Account.new_ClientStatus = '100000000' OR Account.new_ClientStatus = '100000001')
AND     (AnnAccs.LastPeriod = '1' OR CorpTax.LastPeriod = '1' OR SelfAss.LastPeriod = '1')
```

Or you can add [ROW_NUMBER()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to each of your subqueries and limit it to the top result (RowNum = 1):

```
SELECT  Account.Name, 
        AnnAccs.PeriodEnd AS AnnAccsPeriodEnd, 
        AnnAccs.LastPeriod AS AnnAccsLastPeriod,
        CorpTax.PeriodEnd AS CorpTaxPeriodEnd, 
        CorpTax.LastPeriod AS CorpTaxLastPeriod,
        SelfAss.PeriodEnd AS SAPeriodEnd, 
        SelfAss.LastPeriod AS SALastPeriod
FROM    dbo.Account 
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  ca.new_PeriodEnd AS PeriodEnd, 
                    ca.new_LastPeriod AS LastPeriod, 
                    ca.new_CorporationTaxActivityId AS AccId,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ca.new_CorporationTaxActivityId ORDER BY ca.new_PeriodEnd DESC) AS RowNum
            FROM    new_corporationtaxactivity  ca
        ) AS CorpTax 
            ON CorpTax.AccId = Account.AccountId 
            AND CorpTax.RowNum = 1
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  aa.new_PeriodEnd AS PeriodEnd, 
                    aa.new_LastPeriod AS LastPeriod, 
                    aa.new_AnnualAccountsActivityId AS AccId,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY aa.new_AnnualAccountsActivityId ORDER BY aa.new_PeriodEnd DESC) AS RowNum
            FROM    new_annualaccountsactivity aa
        ) AS AnnAccs 
            ON AnnAccs.AccId = Account.AccountId
            AND AnnAccs.RowNum = 1
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  sa.new_PeriodEnd AS PeriodEnd, 
                    sa.new_LastPeriod AS LastPeriod, 
                    sa.new_SelfAssessmentActivityId AS AccId,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sa.new_SelfAssessmentActivityId ORDER BY sa.new_PeriodEnd DESC) AS RowNum
            FROM    new_selfassessmentactivity sa
        ) As SelfAss 
            ON SelfAss.AccId = Account.AccountId
            AND SelfAss.RowNum = 1
WHERE   (Account.new_ClientStatus = '100000000' OR Account.new_ClientStatus = '100000001')
AND     (AnnAccs.LastPeriod = '1' OR CorpTax.LastPeriod = '1' OR SelfAss.LastPeriod = '1');
```

Comment: Amazing, second one works like a charm! Thanks so much Gareth!!! :) (The first failed because I'm accessing views)